Интерпретатор Python не может найти файл
В этой программе интерпретатор не может найти изображения. Я, скорее всего , их не так сохранил или неправильно указал путь к ним, но я не знаю как сделать это правильно.
Вот код:
import requests, json, turtle

iss = turtle.Turtle()

def setup(window):
    global iss

    window.setup(1000, 500)
    window.bgpic('earth.gif')
    window.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180, 90)
    turtle.register_shape('iss.gif')
    iss.shape('iss.gif')

def mov_iss(lat, long):
    global iss

    iss.penup()
    iss.goto(lat, long)
    iss.pendown()

def track_iss():
    url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'

    response = requests.get(url)

    if (response.status_code == 200):
        response_dictionary = json.loads(response.text)
        position = response_dictionary['iss_position']
        # print('Координаты МКС: ', position['longitude'] + ',' + position['latitude'])
        lat = float(position['latitude'])
        long = float(position['longitude'])
        mov_iss(lat, long)
    else:
        print('Хьюстон, у нас проблема:', response.status_code)
    widget = turtle.getcanvas()
    widget.after(5000, track_iss())


def main():
    global iss

    screen = turtle.Screen()
    setup(screen)
    track_iss()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    turtle.mainloop()

Вот ошибка
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python Erik Frimen\ch10\MKS\iss.py", line 48, in <module>   
    main()
  File "c:\Python Erik Frimen\ch10\MKS\iss.py", line 43, in main       
    setup(screen)
  File "c:\Python Erik Frimen\ch10\MKS\iss.py", line 9, in setup       
    window.bgpic('earth.gif')
  File "C:\Python\Lib\turtle.py", line 1473, in bgpic
    self._bgpics[picname] = self._image(picname)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\turtle.py", line 473, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=self.cv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4151, in __init__     
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4098, in __init__     
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)        
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "earth.gif": no such file or directory 


лучши приведи полный текст ошибки для начала. Пока что тут до изображений дело не доходит. А лучше просто переименуй папки так, чтобы в названиях были только английские буквы.

трейс ошибки тоже нужно приводить текстом, а не фотографией.

Я теперь изменил все названия на английские и всё равно ошибка осталась

самый простой способ - укажите полный абсолютный путь к вашим файлам, а не только названия. потому что скрипт пытается открыть их из рабочей директории C:\Users\user, где их, очевидно нет.

Спасибо.Теперь всё работает

Я обычно беру путь к текущему файлу скрипта (он есть в переменной __file__), потом получаю папку, в которой он лежит - я делаю через pathlib (from pathlib import Path): parent_path = Path(__file__).parent. Путь к нужному файлу в этой папке собирается так: earth_path = parent_path / 'earth.gif'. Для turtle возможно нужно будет преобразовать в строку, для этого просто обернуть все в str: earth_path = str(parent_path / 'earth.gif')
